# PHP code is showing when i show the source in the browser

Tags: php

I have tried to use templates to be able to make a multilingual web site, so i created a folder called languages containing en.php and fr.php
here is the code for en.php:

```
<?php
class Index {

    public $filename;
    public $assigned_vars = array();

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this -> assigned_vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function display() {
        if (file_exists($this -> filename)) {
            $output = file_get_contents($this -> filename);
            foreach ($this->assigned_vars as $key => $value) {
                $output = preg_replace('/{' . $key . '}/', $value, $output);
            }
            echo $output;
        } else {
            echo "*** Missing template ***";
        }
    }

}

$index = new Index;
$index -> filename = "templates/index1.php";
$index -> set('page_title', "Welcome");
$index -> set('first_name', "Welcome to our website.");
$index -> display();
?>
```

and here is the code for fr.php:

```
<?php
class Index {

    public $filename;
    public $assigned_vars = array();

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this -> assigned_vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function display() {
        if (file_exists($this -> filename)) {
            $output = file_get_contents($this -> filename);
            foreach ($this->assigned_vars as $key => $value) {
                $output = preg_replace('/{' . $key . '}/', $value, $output);
            }
            echo $output;
        } else {
            echo "*** Disparus modèle ***";
        }
    }

}

$index = new Index;
$index -> filename = "templates/index1.php";
$index -> set('page_title', "Bienvenue");
$index -> set('first_name', "Bienvenue sur notre site.");
$index -> display();
?>
```

then i created a folder called templates and created a file called index1.php

and here is index1.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{page_title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {first_name}
        <br/>
        <a href="?lang=en-us">english</a>
        <a href ="?lang=fr">French</a><br />
        <?php
        echo strftime("Y", time());
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then i created the regular index.php
and here is the code for index.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    setcookie('language_test', $_GET['lang'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    if ($_GET['lang'] == "fr") {
        require ('languages/fr.php');
    } else {
        require ('languages/en.php');
    }
} else {
    require ('languages/en.php');
}
?>
```

here is my problem when i try to show index.php in my browser it works fine but the php code in index1.php doesn't show any of this strftime();, but when i try to view the source of this 
index.php
it's showing me this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Welcome to our website.
        <br/>
        <a href="?lang=en-us">english</a>

        <a href ="?lang=fr">French</a><br />
        <?php
        echo strftime("Y", time());
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance. and sorry for being so long and sorry for my awful english.

Comment: Your template engine doesn't execute PHP code. Which one is it?

Comment: Oh, and "Disparus modèle" is not a good translation, to put it lightly.

Comment: Why don't you make each Index class extend a common base class, to avoid all of that duplication?

Comment: well this is a sample class and so sorry for the translation i actually am trying to do a sign up form and it will be in like 7 languages and i have translators for them so the problem will be the birth date as i am trying to make them as a for loop and it should be included in the template so i wouldn't put it over and over and over again. and it's not a template engine i am trying to create on of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are invoking `file_get_contents($this -> filename);` it just converts `strftime("Y", time());` part as string. So it does not execute.

In the `index1.php` you should use `{time}` instead of

```
<?php
echo strftime("Y", time());
?>
```

So It'll look like

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{page_title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {first_name}
    <br/>
    <a href="?lang=en-us">english</a>
    <a href ="?lang=fr">French</a><br />
    {time}
</body>
```

Now add time in `en.php` or `fr.php` like bellow

```
$index -> set('time', strftime("%Y", time()));
```

Its better not to re-invent a template library. There are plenty available. See this blog post [top 25 php template engines](http://www.livexp.net/technology/php/top-25-php-template-engines.html)

Comment: @MohamedHassan this is because `strftime` format characters starts with `%`. like `strftime("%Y", time());`

Comment: you were right i didn't notice the % before the Y so sorry man and it worked after  i added the %, what do you think if i have a for loop in index 1.php what should i do

Comment: I'd recommend not to re-invent the wheel, Use some already implemented parser. Like [smarty](http://smarty.net)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who tried to help me.
i looked at another question and i found my answer without using smarty

```
<?php
class Index {

    public $filename;
    public $assigned_vars = array();

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this -> assigned_vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function display() {
        if (file_exists($this -> filename)) {
            ob_start();
            include ($this -> filename);
            $output = ob_get_clean();
            foreach ($this->assigned_vars as $key => $value) {
                $output = preg_replace('/{' . $key . '}/', $value, $output);
            }
            echo $output;
        } else {
            echo "*** Missing template error ***";
        }

    }

}

$index = new Index;
$index -> filename = "templates/index1.php";
$index -> set('page_title', "Welcome");
$index -> set('content', "Welcome to our website.");
$index -> display();
?>
```

the problem as Shiplu stated that i invoked file_get_contents();

and now i can do my for loop without any problems in index1.php

so i hope i got something useful for you guys
and really this is the best website ever,
Thanks to everyone tried to help me.

Have a wonderful day all of you